# Netlogo Probabilistic movement by a turtle to surrounding patches

Tags: netlogo

I want a turtle to Probabilistically move to one of the patches in it's neighbors. The value of probability for patch variable.
This is quite similar to genetic algorithm selection.
I wish to implement any selection technique possible.

**UPDATE:**

*Value of probability of a patch:* means the chance of getting that patch selected. So a patch with zero probability have get no chance of getting selected. And a patch with 100 percent probability will always get selected.:

**UPDATE2:**
The following I found I think does so but I think understand it quite:

```
 report last first filter [first ? >= rand-num] probabilities
```

The tried this other code,please check if it makes sense:

```
ask neighbors4[calculate-proabalities]
let patchset neighbors4
  let pick random-float sum [score] of patchset
  let winner nobody
  ask patchset[
    if (is-patch? winner = false)
    [
      ifelse (score > pick)
       [set winner self]
       [set pick pick - score]
       ]
    ]
  report winner
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically repeating code from the Lottery example in the Models Library.  (Attribution would be a good idea.)  It is unclear why you changed the test for the existence of a winner. I would actually discard it altogether, like this.

```
to-report local-winner [#candidates]
  ask #candidates [calculate-score]
  let %pick random-float sum [score] of #candidates
  let %winner nobody
  ask #candidates [
    ifelse score > %pick [ 
       set %winner self stop
    ] [ 
       set %pick (%pick - score)
    ] 
  ]
  report %winner
end

ask myturtle [move-to local-winner neighbors4]
```

Note that this assumes (as in your example code) that a patch can compute its score in isolation.  If not, you will need to make appropriate changes.  Note also that you cannot simply report out from inside the `ask`, which one might be tempted to try.

Answer (score 1):

This is something that can also be achieved with the [`rnd:weighted-one-of`](https://github.com/NetLogo/Rnd-Extension#rndweighted-one-of--agentset-reporter-task) primitive of the [Rnd extension](https://github.com/NetLogo/Rnd-Extension#readme):

```
let winner rnd:weighted-one-of neighbors4 [ [score] of ? ]
```

Comment: Great! Didn't knew of that. Thanks so much!